# Literals (Images & Colors) don't work in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

When I try using literals in a Playground, it shows me like this (doesn't show my image):

[image: anotherExample]
in above i add image or UIImage literal but doesn't show their contents.\

and also this with colors (I can't even see colors):

[image: another example]

Comment: You should post your code as text

Comment: Start typing 'Color', and the dropdown will provide 'Color Literal picker'

Comment: @Moritz thanks for editing my question, i searched a lot but can't find solution

Comment: @CZ54 i do that & chose Color Literal but it's show only white color

Comment: @MasihKia once the white square is visible, you can click in it to display a color picker

Comment: @CZ54 as you can see in pictures it doesn't also show colors side of their names

Comment: i think this  is bug for my Xcode or missing something

Comment: @MasihKia In the capture you are typing UIColor. Just tap 'color'

Comment: @Moritz i using 9.0.1 , latest one

Comment: @CZ54 i do your guide, edit my question and add image of what happened when i'm taping on color literal

Comment: The white square should be prompted with blue border if you were selecting it.

Comment: @CZ54 yes it has blue border, when i click on it, i don't know why it doesn't show my image literal also

Comment: @RezaK were you able to use Image Literal? It doesn't work for me. Although my images are in Asset catalog

Comment: @ChanchalRaj yes it's worked for me, but i can't remember what was my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151322/9136962

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you type `Color Literal`, a white box appears. In order to set the required colour, tap on that white box to select the colour from Color Picker.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: i did that before, as you can see in my image, i think there is something wrong in my Xcode

Comment: Clean and run your project. Sometimes this also causes unusual issues.

Comment: i'm did that but doesn't change, even in Playground

Comment: @MasihKia are you double clicking on the white box? When you first add the Colour Literal it will be white. You then have to actually set it. You don't get an automatic drop down of different colours.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks, thats work with double click, Now my Problem is with images literal, i can't see their contents in their little square, but image is there.

Comment: @MasihKia did you double click the image icon thing? Also, image literals only work with image in Asset catalogs. Is your image in an asset catalog?

Comment: @MasihKia Can you add a screenshot of your asset catalog to the OP.

Comment: @Fogmeister i do this in playground, and edit my question with new image

Comment: @MasihKia OK, so going back to my question and statement... “Are you using an asset catalog? Image Literals only work with images in asset catalogs”... You are not using an asset catalog because you can’t use them in playgrounds. And so image literals won’t work.

Comment: @MasihKia Except that isn’t a playground and if you double click the icon in that screenshot there you’ll be able to pick the image. This isn’t hard to understand. Image literals require asset catalogs.

Comment: @Fogmeister it shows but dosen't shows image inside square like this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZpFk.png

Comment: @MasihKia are you reading the parts where I said “Image Literals require an asset catalog”? You seem to not be understanding that. In order to use Image Literals you need to have your images in an asset catalog. Have a google for Xcode asset catalog. You need on of those if you want to use image literals. If you don’t have an asset catalog you can’t use image literals. I’m not sure how else I can phrase this?

Comment: @Fogmeister i know & do this now & sent picture for you: i.stack.imgur.com/Y4EKw.png 
but doesn't change anything

Comment: @MasihKia I give in. You said you are in a playground yes? You cannot (AFAIK) use Asset catalogs in a playground. You have shown a screenshot of your playground. It shows an image that is not in an asset catalog. You then seem to have shown a selection of random images from the internet. If you are not in a playground and you are using an asset catalog then double click the icon. It will show a way to select the image you want to use.

Comment: @MasihKia The first lime of your question “When I try using image literals in a playground...”. You can’;t use image literals in a playground because you need an asset catalog to use image literals and you can’t use asset catalogs in playgrounds (AFAIK).

Comment: @MasihKia If you have got something wrong in your question then update your question. I am going now. This is getting too ciurcular.

Comment: @Fogmeister no i do that in project application not in the playground, did you see my image send you, that is my work

Comment: Not working any more. Out dated

Answer (score 21):

Type `#colorLiteral()` and `#imageLiteral()` to see a color picker or image picker respectively.

[image: color literal or image literal in xcode placeholder]

**Note:** Image picker will list your images at `Assets.xcassets`.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you add to the class `import UIKit`