# How to use Image Literal in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode13

The most used feature is missing in Xcode 13

> Image Literal
>
> #imageLiteral()

these commands do not seem to be working. A similar change has happened for Color Literals as well.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/69346531/1187415 ?

Comment: @MartinR That's not consistently working for me

Comment: I'd give up if I were you. Image literals and color literals have not worked usefully in years. Xcode 13  is merely the latest iteration. If, as your question implies, you use them a lot, stop doing so.

Comment: In Xcode 13, use #imageLiteral( without the closing parenthesis. That will put the literal in the code and is the best workaround thus far. Code completion no longer works for literals in Xcode 13.

Comment: @Rajesh, add images to the asset catalog first. The image literal requires images to be in an asset catalog before it will open.

Answer (score 31):

There is no longer image literal :(

You may try:

```
Who.What = UIImage(named: "catImage")
```

Comment: This is simpler than #imageLiteral( because the popup picker sometimes does not works

Comment: Xcode 14.2 allows one to use an image literal simply as typing

imageView.image = #imageLiteral()

at which point the #imageLiteral() in the above changed to a clickable icon allowing you to select any image you have placed into the projects assets.

Answer (score 17):

I came up with a workaround

Create code snippets for color literal and image literal like below

Color

```
#colorLiteral()
```

[image: colorLiteral]

And add completion shortcut as you want, Example: `colorLiteral`.
Do same for Image literal

Image

```
#imageLiteral()
```

[image: imageLiteral]

And add completion shortcut as you want. Call those completion shortcuts in your code to get `color` and `image` literals.

[image: colorLiteral]
[image: imageLiteral]

Answer (score 11):

type Who.What = #imageLiteral(
Currently it works like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

I used

`UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image_asset_name")`

and it works perfectly fine on XCode 13.2.1

Comment: Confirmed in Monterey

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable at the top of your struct to hold the color and image literals before you use them in the view body.

```
let color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1411764771, green: 0.3960784376, blue: 0.5647059083, alpha: 1)
let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cherry1")
```

creating a shortcut is handy but it doesn't solve the problem of Xcode not allowing literals to be used as parameters to views.

This is a nice feature in Xcode and you may find it cool for small projects, but the best way to handle images, colours and other resources is to look into a package like R.Swift or Swiftgen

https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen

https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

I prefer swiftgen since R.swift is not currently working with M1 Macs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make Xcode auto complete colorLiteral, but you can still use the inline color picker.

This is a workaround which works in Xcode 14.2.

Where you want the color picker, enter any color full `colorLiteral`

```
#colorLiteral(red: 0.1411764771, green: 0.3960784376, blue: 0.5647059083, alpha: 1)
```

Xcode will then display the color picker which you can use.[image]